# Dynamically Align X & Y Possisions in pdf with trailing 0s

Tags: php, pdf

I am using a pdf generator in php and it is using php variables and putting them in a dynamic pdf, depending on what the user has entered.

One of these variables is money, i want to align the 0s on the end of the money so rather than looking like this

[image]

I would like it to look like this

```
Value:           14.00
VAT at 20%:       2.80
Total Value:     16.80
```

I have got the length of the int, but i am wondering if there would be a way of dynamically aligning the 0s, to have it work with 100s and 1000s too. this is the code i am using at the moment to set the values X and Y co-ordinates

```
$pdf->addText(230, 200, 8, "Total Value (Exl VAT): ");
$pdf->addText(400, 200, 8, $TotalValue);

$pdf->addText(230, 160, 8, "VAT at " . $VATRate . "%");
$pdf->addText(400, 160, 8, $PaidVAT);

$pdf->addText(230, 140, 8, "Total Value (Inc VAT): ");
$pdf->addText(400, 140, 8, $TotalPaid);

$pdf->addText(230, 120, 8, "Currency: " . $clientCurrency);
```

The `addText` function takes the values ($x, $y, $fontSize, $text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *hack* that could work :)

Since you use a monospaced font, you could add text like this:

```
$pdf->addText(230, 200, 8, "Total Value (Exl VAT): ");
$pdf->addText(400, 200, 8, str_pad($TotalValue, 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT));

$pdf->addText(230, 160, 8, "VAT at " . $VATRate . "%");
$pdf->addText(400, 160, 8, str_pad($PaidVAT, 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT));

$pdf->addText(230, 140, 8, "Total Value (Inc VAT): ");
$pdf->addText(400, 140, 8, str_pad($TotalPaid, 10, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

This would padd your $TotalValue string (and others accordingly) to 10-characters strings, filling the missing characters on the left with empty space. So the `$TotalValue` of `14.00` and VAT of `2.80` will be printed like this:

```
     14.00
      2.80
```

Comment: That worked great thank you! I have been fiddling around with this for hours trying to find a solution

Comment: Great to hear that :) 
Bear in mind that the solution to this would also be a properly styled HTML used with some kind of HTML2PDF converter (I used dompdf with little effort and great results). Using HTML will allow for easy styling and no hacks, which should also work for different fonts.

Comment: I am using a private company one, works just as well though